# Linq XML Read Element with Attribute

Tags: xml, linq

Trying to get data from the second row.
In this second row i need to read the:-
col 
subrows - rows.

Its very confusing a with my code i get all the rows ...
Please help how to go about it..I cant figure out how to work with complex xml documents

C#

```
        path = path + "/PongraweDriver.xml";
        XElement root = XElement.Load(path);

        IEnumerable<XElement> datasource =
             from el in root.Descendants("table")
             where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "Eco driving"
             select el;

        IEnumerable<XElement> rowdata =
             from elm in datasource.Descendants("row")
             //where (string)el.Attribute("name") == "Eco driving"
             select elm;

        foreach (XElement elm in rowdata)
            Console.WriteLine(elm);
```

XML

```
     <table cols="3" flags="16781440" id="drivers_group_ecodriving" 
       name="Eco driving" rows="3">
        <header>
            <col name="№"/>
            <col name="Grouping"/>
            <col name="Count"/>
        </header>
        <row>
            <col txt="1" val="0" vt="0"/>
            <col txt="Kyaw Min Oo" val="0" vt="0"/>
            <col txt="5" val="5" vt="2"/>
            <subrows>
                <row>
                    <col txt="1.1" val="0" vt="0"/>
                    <col txt="Harsh Brake Km/h.s" val="0" vt="0"/>
                    <col txt="2" val="2" vt="2"/>
                </row>
                <row>
                    <col txt="1.2" val="0" vt="0"/>
                    <col txt="OverSpeed-Medium" val="0" vt="0"/>
                    <col txt="3" val="3" vt="2"/>
                </row>
            </subrows>
        </row>
     </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used xml linq in c# to put results into a datatable.  See code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            XElement table = doc.Descendants("table").FirstOrDefault();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable((string)table.Attribute("name"));

            XElement header = table.Element("header");
            foreach (XElement col in header.Elements("col"))
            {
                dt.Columns.Add((string)col.Attribute("name"), typeof(string));
            }
            foreach (XElement row in table.Descendants("row"))
            {
                string[] rowData = row.Elements("col").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("txt")).ToArray();
                dt.Rows.Add(rowData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your a Genius.. Just what i needed.. Sorry to bother you. but how would i choose the table with the attribute. right now you have used firstOrDfault. How do i tell it to load the table with the attribute náme'= eco

Comment: I had to use firstOrDefault when using Descendants/Elements since you need only one table. doc.Descendants("table").Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("name") == "eco – nadeem").FirstOrDefault();